# Adding text to this line

Tags: sql, rounding

I'm a novice so please excuse the simplicity of this. I am trying to get a total ammount, trim the excess decimal places than append some text.. it all works until I try ROUND it

ROUND(CAST(ServiceFee * COUNT(UserID) AS VARCHAR(20)),0) + CAST(' yen' as VARCHAR(20))

Thanks in advance

Comment: Tagged as SQL, looks like that to me too

Comment: What dialect of SQL? Looks like MySQL, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the dialect of SQL.

For example, in MySQL the `+` operator is for mathematical addition only. If you want to *concatenate* the values, should use `CONCAT()` (in MySQL) or the `||` operator (other DBMSes that support standard SQL).
You're also doing a redundant CAST within ROUND() because the ROUND function expects its argument to be numeric.

So here's the fixed statement in MySQL:

```
CONCAT(ROUND(ServiceFee * COUNT(UserID), 0), ' yen')
```

Or in standard SQL:

```
CAST(ROUND(ServiceFee * COUNT(UserID), 0) AS VARCHAR(20)) || ' yen'
```

(the CAST is probably redundant, but I kept it just in case you had a purpose for it)

Comment: The + operator concatenates strings just fine in MSSQL.

Comment: That's why I asked user "Mark Hollas" which dialect of SQL he is talking about.

Answer (score 0):

You have to round the value before you cast it:

```
CAST(ROUND(ServiceFee * COUNT(UserID),0) AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' yen'
```

Comment: The + operator will attempt to *add* the numeric values of the two strings. The expression `'1' + ' yen'` returns just `1` in MySQL

Comment: @intgr: That depends on what database you use. In MSSQL it doesn't attempt to add the values as both are strings. As it works before the round() was called, the + operator is obviously not the issue.